# Wrapping list items inside div (in a Repeater)

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, gridview, repeater

I have a list of Report object displayed using Repeater control. In the Report class there is a RecipientsList which is a List of string. I have following code inside the repeater to render the list as a comma separated list.

The code is working fine. Currently it is creating a string inside the div (which has class= "repeaterLine")

I need each string to be in separate div element. There should be as many div elements as the number of recipients. Is it possible to achieve it in **ASP.Net markup** (only)?

Markup  inside Repeater

```
 <div class="repeaterLine">
   <%# String.Join(", ",((ServicesSupportSite.UI.Report)Container.DataItem).RecipientsList)%>
 </div>
```

Report Class

```
public class Report
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> RecipientsList { get; set; }
}
```

**REFERENCE**

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159211/scenarios-where-linq-is-handy

Comment: Could you post your entire repeater code block if possible?

Comment: @bUKaneer What I have provided in the question is the only element inside the ItemTemplate. It has no header template. I think, that is the complete information about the repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LINQ `.Select()` to wrap the strings in RecipientsList in `<div>` tags, like this:

```
 <div class="repeaterLine">
   <%# String.Join(", ",((ServicesSupportSite.UI.Report)Container.DataItem).RecipientsList.Select(x => "<div>" + x + "</div>")%>
 </div>
```